# How to customize the ZBar SDK in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, qr-code, zbar-sdk

I implemented the zbar sdk to read the QRCode.All is working fine and now i want to customize the camera.Please help me how can i customize the camera using ZBar SDK.
My Camera screen should be like below

[image]

Comment: customize means want to add overlay on camera ?

Comment: zbar sdk have cameraoverlay property make uiview and set that view as overlay reader.overlay = "yourviewname".check this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613476/add-overlay-over-top-of-zbar-scanner